# write SQL query that takes its own output as input

Tags: query, oracle-sql-developer, recursive, self-join

In a table that displays how trades are related to each other, starting from one trade, I want to find all other trades that relate to the first trade:

```
713613  PostPTETradeIDs 718478
713613  PrePTETradeId   711314
718478  PostPTETradeIDs 739522
718478  PrePTETradeId   713613
```

In this example, trade `718478` was created by splitting `713613` (row 1); and `739522` was created from `718478` (row 3), etc. (a PTE splits a trade into two).

```
select trade_id, keyword_name, keyword_value 
from trade_keyword 
where (keyword_name like 'LinkedTo' or keyword_name like 'PrePTETradeId' or keyword_name like 'PostPTETradeIDs' )
    and trade_id in('718478', '739522','713613')
order by trade_id;
```

My goal is to identify trades that belong together and come from one another.

Currently, using the above query, I must fill all the `TRADE_ID`s manually, i.e. start with `713613`, run the query, see that `718478` came from it, then run the query again searching for `718478`, too, to find that `739522` came from it, etc.

I would like to make this recursive, such that it will, in one query, given some starting `TRADE_ID`(s), find all `TRADE_ID`s that are related to these via any path of any of these relations.

In other words, if column 1 is `X` and column 3 is `f(X)`, then I want at once a list of all `X`, `f(X)`, `f(f(X))`, `f(f(f(X)))`, etc.

Preferably, there would be another column that lists the distance in steps upwards or downwards, where the `PostPTETradeIDs` relation is upward and the `PrePTETradeID` is downward (the `LinkedTo` relationship does not change the counter):

`713613` is distance 0,
`718478` is distance 1,
`739522` is distance 2.

I am using Oracle SQL. Is this issue better adressed via a subquery, and if so, how can it be made recursive; or some other functionality?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [subquery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-2017) with the same table in both the primary and sub queries, join on trade_id = keyword_value

Depending on how many levels a trade could have it might get complex, but this should get you going in the right direction.